# Colorize ifort output

Tags: fortran, colorize, intel-fortran

I know gcc produces colored output for the error messages. Does a similar feature exist in ifort as well ?

Comment: I gather it could be made to work on *nix, but on Windows ansi color is not so well taken anymore. In either case, not ifort's fault in any way. Since you're not using an IDE, I'll go and assume you're talking about linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done by external tools which are placed on top of gcc so that they can process output and colorize it (example: [colorgcc](http://schlueters.de/colorgcc.html)). You could take a look at it, which is written in perl, and see if it's easy to adapt to fortan output errors..